# How to replace permalink in Wordpress with the value from a custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm really confused by custom values in Wordpress. None of the resources I've found have made much sense to me and answered my specific problem so was hoping I'd be able to get some assistance here.

So on each of my blog posts I have a custom field with the name 'amazon link'. The value for this custom field is in the form 'http://www.amazon.com/abc'.

I am trying to replace the permalink to each post on category pages with the value from the custom field. So I'm thinking that I would edit the following code:

```
<?php
        endif;

        if ( is_single() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
        endif;
    ?>
```

and replace the 'get_permalink()' bit in the section shown below:

```
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
```

But what code would I need to replace it with?

Thanks in advance for your attention and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to get the post meta value. From the docs:

```
get_post_meta ( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```

Therefore, you'd use something like the following:

```
else :
    $amazon_link = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'amazon_link', true ) );
    the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . $amazon_link . '">', '</a></h1>' );
```

Keep in mind, your meta keys shouldn't have spaces in them...So I don't know if `amazon_link` is your actual meta key.

Comment: Awesome - that worked a treat thank you. A couple of points I discovered while trying to implement this that may help future viewers of this thread.

1. Capitalisation matters! Key_name is not the same as key_name

2. I didn't realise you have to store the code get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'amazon_link', true ) in a variable. I had seen this code proposed in other threads on a similar topic but it wasn't working for me. This is why.

Comment: @Harry , you actually don't have to store the meta in a variable...I just did that for readability. You could use the following just as well: `the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'amazon_link', true ) ) . '">', '</a></h1>' );`